# Header Inclusion Performance

Tags: c++, c, compilation, header, shared-libraries

I often avoided including large header files only to use one function, believing that doing so is a performance loss. So, I would just implement the function in code, and it would work as expected.

At last, I realized that that pretty much destroys the whole concept of libraries, despite being time consuming.

Thinking of it, C compilers tend to dynamically link programs to the libc shared library *(You can see which libraries are dynamically linked by using the command: ldd <program_path>)*. So, doesn't that mean that linking to the whole library is performance-consuming enough, that I need not care about individual file inclusions ?

Do executables tend to include the whole library functions, or just the used functions ?
I'd like to know if there are any C / C++ differences ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"So, doesn't that mean that linking to the whole library is performance-consuming enough, that I need not care about individual file inclusions ?"*

I don't exactly get, where you see the performance problems here. Including header files is optimized by the c preprocessor, linking is a different stage, and optimized by the linker.
Though there are often good reasons, just to use forward declarations of functions or classes, instead of including a whole header. But that's not so much performance related.

> *"Do executables tend to include the whole library functions, or just the used functions ?"*

If you use static linkage, the linker will only add used functions.

> *"I'd like to know if there are any C / C++ differences .."*

No.

Comment: That's good. When I said: performance-consuming, I actually meant: startup time consuming, due to the fact that the linker runs alongside the program

Comment: @AmrAyman Well I suspect you mean dynamical library loading? In this case it's also only the used functions, which need to be resolved by the dynamic library loader.

Comment: There are differences between C and C++: C++ headers often contain lots of templates and inline-functions, which makes including them more costly (C does not have templates and inline-functions in headers are far fewer). The committee is working on it. Still, include all the headers needed and no more.

Comment: @Deduplicator I interpreted this point asking about the linker. Despite the template linking costs, there aren't really essential differences IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer of πάντα ῥεῖ:

- Including a header file does not have any cost at runtime. Including a header file will cause the preprocessor to dump the contents of the header file into your program at the place where you include the header. C header files do not contain anything that causes the compiler to emit code when you include them. While it is possible for headers to do so, this is considered bad style and frowned upon.
- On systems that use `ELF` for its binaries (Linux, BSD, Solaris, Unix, ...) every function except for those with `static` linkage are called through the PLT. This is a table with a little stub of code for each function that can be called. When your program starts, the PLT contains only placeholders. The first time you call a function, the linker resolves its address and replaces the code in the PLT so the next call to the function does not go through the linker and is in fact not significantly slower than a call that does not go through the PLT. The extra cost is one jump instruction.
- When your program starts, the linker loads all libraries your program depends on into the address space of your process. This does not mean that the libraries will actually be read from the hard disk; the operating system only ever reads the parts from the hard disk that are actually needed.
- It is possible to tell the linker to only load a library once you call the first function in it. This is usually not a good thing but there are rare use cases where this makes sense, like having a program that can be used in an environment where the library you want to use is not available.
- Don't worry too much about the overhead of dynamic libraries. It is negible and should not matter at all unless under extreme circumstances. Perform measurements before optimizing these things.